# Pointers to schema evolution and semi-automated instance migration

Tags: reference-request, databases

**QUESTION EDITED**

Since this question wasn't clear, I'll rephrase. See question-history for original.

I'm looking for academic papers that describe schema evolution on documents (1) in a *generic* way. More specifically some questions I'm hoping to see answered in part: given a schema A and documents adhering to schema A:

- what type of atomic 'change-operations' may occur on schema A for instances of schema A to be compatible with the newly created schema A+.
- in general terms, does an exhaustive list of these 'change-operations' (A) even exist (theoretically) or (B) would this be db-dependent? Intuitively I think the answer is (A)
- Assuming (A) any pointers to such a list? (2)
- Given a schema A and a schema B, is it possible to deconstruct the delta  between these two schemas to their atomic 'change-operations'?
- Given the above, theoretically, it seems possible to either:

  - do automatic migration of all instances of schema A to adhere to A+
  - list where manual intervention is needed because of incompatibilities.

1) with documents I mean objects generally stored in nosql document-databases. I.e.: objects with complex types / nesting. The misplaced term nosql I used in the original question was an attempt to point this out.

2) Although pretty old [Recent advances in schema and ontology
evolution](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.194.2805&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is an example of what I'm looking for. It illustrates a couple of 'change operations' as follows (through Moto et. al 2007 specifically mentioning Xml schema changes, copied verbatim) :

> 1. Add a new optional or required element to a type
> 2. Delete an element from a type
> 3. Add new top-level constructs like complex types
> 4. Remove top-level constructs
> 5. Change the semantics of an element without changing its syntax – for instance, if the new version of an application treats the implicit
>      units of a column to be in metric where previous versions did not
> 6. Refactor a schema in a way that does not affect instance validation – for instance, factoring out common local type definitions into a
>      single global type definition
> 7. Nest a collection of elements inside another element
> 8. Flatten an element by replacing it by its children
> 9. Rename an element or change its namespace
> 10. Change an element’s maximum or minimum multiplicity
> 11. Modify an element’s type, either by changing it from one named type to another or adding or changing a restriction or extension
> 12. Change an element’s default value
> 13. Reorder elements in a type

Clearly this doesn't cover all change operations possible on a document schema. Missing for example are change-operations related to object-references.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Software engineering *as an academic discipline* is ontopic here ([1](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-is-our-stance-on-software-engineering), [2](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/711/what-kinds-of-computer-engineering-do-we-consider-computer-science-enough-to-be)). This is a request for academic references, so it *seems* to be ontopic to me. Community votes, please!

Comment: [I removed a discussion about the scope of another site as well as bickering. Please remain civil and express your opinion about *this question*, in the form of close votes if need be.]

Comment: Thanks @Raphael. Updated by question to hopefully be a better fit. Removed previous question (still avail in history) since it would become a complete mess . If that's not according to rules, I'll re-add original question

Comment: @Geert-Jan Well, to me this looks like a reasonable question. I have no expertise in the area at all, so I can't help you further there. Good luck!